# End-of-semester presentation idea on PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am supposed to give a 30-minute class presentation on any PDE subjects as end-of-semester project. Do you have any pet subject you would love to suggest?

I have very little applied maths in my background, therefore I am not very advanced in PDE; I took this class as elective only. Hence I prefer a subject that is not in advanced level, but one that comes handy with lots of online resources.

Thank you very much for your time and effort.

---

POST SCRIPT: My class uses John Davis' *Introduction to Applied PDE* as textbook. My professor moves slowly and covers only the first few chapters of the book, namely, Intro to PDE; Fourier Methods: Separation of Variables; Full, Sine & Cosine Fourier Series; Sturm-Liouville Theory. Thanks again.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a short summary of the topics you have touched upon in your course. (Partly because it won't do you any good if we suggest a subject you have already covered in class!)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will edit shortly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

From what you described, you have not covered Method of Characteristics in any detail at all? Then for a 30 minute presentation a reasonable thing to do would be to introduce the method of characteristics and discuss the shock formation for the [inviscid Burger's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation).

If you have already done that in class, a further extension would be to read a bit about the [Fermi-Pasta-Ulam experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Pasta%E2%80%93Ulam_problem) and present it. Richard Palais' article in [the Bulletin](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1997-34-04/S0273-0979-97-00732-5/home.html) has a wealth of information, much of it may be a bit too advanced. You should probably just skip sections 1 and 2, and read sections 3.1 through 3.5; in there Palais gives some pretty good intuition on what is happening and why the problem is interesting.

Comment: Thanks! Let me take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest presenting the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis theorem and its applications, using e.g. Stein's functional analysis or Hörmander's PDE book.

Comment: Thank you! I will give your idea a serious look.